Airflow failed to get the value of dag_run.conf when passing it as arguments in a function
Hi I have a customOperator that requires to pass some values in a dictionary.
from get_rec_time import get_rec_time

with DAG(
    dag_id="",
    description="",
    schedule=CALENDAR,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    tags=[],
) as dag:
    
    start_date = "{{ dag_run.conf['start_date'] }}"
    end_date = "{{ dag_run.conf['end_date'] }}"

    sql_rec_parameter = get_rec_time(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, freq='M') # Did not pass the value to the function args

    with TaskGroup(
        group_id="my_task_group", prefix_group_id=True
    ) as my_task_group:


        my_task = MyCustomOperator(
            task_id = "my_task_id",
            name=f"my_task_name",
            job_name='my_job_name,
            additional_info=json.dumps(
                {
                    "EXTRAS": {
                        "country": "abc",
                        "start_date": start_date, # Gets the value as expected
                        "end_date": end_date, # Gets the value as expected
                    "MORE_EXTRAS": sql_rec_parameter
                    },
                }
            ),
        )

I have also tried to do something like this:
"SQL_REC_PARAMETERS": get_rec_time(start_date=created_at, freq='M')
directly in the dict. Yet the issue remains.
In get_rec_time, the start_date & end_date are passed as "{{ dag_run.conf['start_date'] }}" and "{{ dag_run.conf['end_date'] }}" respectively. Rather than, value provided when running the DAG, for eg, "2023-01-01".
Kindly help. Thank you.
